# what does below method does in javascript?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am new to javascript. i have below native method in my GWT code. what does it indicates? Please help me.

```
private native void fireEvent(Element node) /*-{
        node.click();
    }-*/;
```

Comment: It seems to fire the `click` event of an element, e.g. of `<button onclick="alert(0)">but</button>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fires the onClick function of the Element called.

Answer (score 2):

It mimics the event of the user clicking on the element `node`, i.e. it fakes a click on a particular part of the page (indicated by 'node'), although the actual click part seems to be commented out. This looks more like a prototype.

Comment: It's not a prototype, it GWT's specific notation for inserting native JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It simulates a mouse click on element.